# TextWatcher filter the list but donot update position of elements

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, android-textwatcher

I am developing an android app where i use **TextWatcher** to filter the list.

List gets filter when i type a word in edit text but when i select any item, function select the item from unfiltered list position.
you can see in picture. In first image ... you can see unfiltered list where Aspirine 10mg in at position(0)

[image: in this image... you can see unfiltered list where Aspirine 10mg in at position(0)]

In second image ...this is filtered list... it contains all items containing 'C' ...when i click on first item(at position[0] in filtered list) it will select the item from unfiltered list position[0]

[image: this is filtered list... it contains all items containing 'C' ...when i click on first item(at position[0] in filtered list) it will select the item from unfiltered list position[0]]

Please help me...how can i fix it... following you can see my code too.

```
 grabResults = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grabed_et_search);

     grabResults.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //perform Search
                grabedDb.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        int success = response.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {
                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("mydrugs");

                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                item.put(ITEM_ID, jobj.getString(ITEM_ID));
                                item.put(ITEM_NAME,
                                        jobj.getString(ITEM_NAME));

                                Item_List.add(item);

                            } // for loop ends

                            String[] from = { ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME };
                            int[] to = { R.id.item_name, R.id.item_id };

                            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), Item_List,
                                    R.layout.list_items, from, to);
                            final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_list_listView);
                            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
                            PD.dismiss();
//////// List Item Click Method Starts here ////////
                            myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                                        long id) {
                                    HashMap<String, String> selectedItems = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    selectedItems = Item_List.get(position);
                                    stock_list.add(selectedItems);

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Added To Cart " + stock_list  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I think you have try track selected item position instead position you have to track some unique id of each item.

Comment: @HareshChhelana can you please explain me some scenario...so i can get solution ... i am not good in this field yet :/

Comment: Have you used custom adapter ?

Comment: No , i used SimpleAdapter

Comment: Try replaced "selectedItems = Item_List.get(position);" with "selectedItems = (HashMap<String, String>) myList.getItemAtPosition(position);". Hope that help!